# c# Windows Forms Application: Convert.ToDecimal not producing expected results

Tags: c#

I'm trying to decimalize a variable value from an XML file.
The Code I am using to do this is :

```
//round monitory values to 2 decimal palaces, even if none are given

decimal totalAmount = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(xn.Attributes["totalAmount"].Value), 2);
decimal paid = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(xn.Attributes["paidAmount"].Value), 2);
decimal due = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(xn.Attributes["dueAmount"].Value), 2);
```

Their values in the XML file are :

```
totalAmount="538.0000" 
paidAmount="0.0"
dueAmount="527"
```

What comes out are :

```
totalAmount="538.00"   -  GREAT 
paidAmount="0.0"       -  No Change
dueAmount="527"        -  No Change
```

What I'm trying to get out is

```
totalAmount="538.00" 
paidAmount="0.00"
dueAmount="527.00"
```

Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong ?

thanks

Comment: What difference does it make when they are `decimal`? When you try to convert it to a string or wherever you print the value, that is where you can enforce the 2 decimal places rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing rounding with formatting.

To get the strings you need you would do this:

```
string totalFormatted = totalAmount.ToString("F");
string paidFormatted = paidAmount.ToString("F");
string dueFormatted = dueAmount.ToString("F");
```